# How to prevent files from being shown in Unity dash?

Tags: unity, files, unity-dash

I don't want file names to be completed in my unity dash, for privacy and security reasons.

Is there a way to disable files from being shown in the dash?

Note that I am able to hide recently used documents from dash, using the privacy settings. What I am interested in is hiding **all** documents from dash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The files and folders lens is just another package in Ubuntu. To remove it all you have to do is:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-files
```

You will have to log out and back in, or reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but isn't having any effect. I probably need to logout and login again, which I can't right now.

Comment: No problem. I forgot to mention that. I edited my answer to include that you need to log in and out or reboot.